# Syntax error in object property assignment

Tags: javascript, object, properties

Code Academy says there are 2 ways to create objects in JavaScript.

**1. object literal notation**

```
var myObject = {     
    key: value,     
    key: value,    
    key: value 
};
```

**2. object constructor approach**

```
var myObject = new Object();
```

Keys can then be added thus:

```
myObj["name"] = "Charlie"; 
myObj.name = "Charlie"; //shorthand for the first
```

Being asked to create 3 objects, I tried different ways to produce the objects with the same values but I am getting an error using the template provided above. My code is pasted below:

```
var object1 = {
    1: 2,
    7: 3,
    4: 5
};

var object2 = new Object();
object2['1'] = 2;
object2['7'] = 3;
object2['4'] = 5;

var object3 = new Object();
object3.1 = 2;
object3.7 = 3;
object3.4 = 5;
```

Code Academy gave me an error and to figure out where exactly it was, I used Chrome's console. Tying each object creation separately on Chrome's console, `object1` and `object2` could be created but not `object3` which produces the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`

Changing `object3`'s code to (changing keys from numbers to strings):

```
var object3 = new Object();
object3.'1' = 2;
object3.'7' = 3;
object3.'4' = 5;
```

produces the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string`

Is it possible to create `object3` using this template/layout to produce values of `object1` or can the key never be a number or string? A string but not a number for the key worked in creating `object2`.

Comment: A property name can't start with a number using 'dot' syntax. object3._1 will work, however because underscores (as well as $ and alphabetical characters) are legal syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the **dot notation**, the keys should be named in the same way variables are (**starts with a letter or _ and contains only letters, numbers and _**).

If the key is not valid to be used as dot notation then it can be used using **bracket notation** like this:

```
obj["key goes here"];
```

Since `1`, `7` and `4` are not valid for dot notation, the only way to use them as key is like this: `obj["4"]` ...

Here is an [**MDN page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) about the basics of objects.

**Example:**

These keys are valid for dot notation:

```
abc;
_a;
R2D2;
_;
_0;
a________a;
```

Thes are not:

```
k-ey;
a b a;
99;
k.e.y;
@@;
```